# Can't link INET library to omnet project correctly Ubuntu 18

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am on ubuntu 18, and I am trying to compile my project where I linked the INET library. It worked fine when I was on ubuntu 16. But now I got these errors on ubuntu 18:

I already added inet library to reference projects.

```
myApp.cc
HelloMsg_m.cc
XedMsg_m.cc
Creating executable: out/gcc-release//SaaS
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::StateSet::setRenderingHint(int) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to  « osgEarth::MapNode::getMapSRS() const »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to  « osg::Group::removeChildren(unsigned int, unsigned int) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::Object::getUserData() »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::AutoTransform::setNormal(osg::Vec3f const&) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to  « osg::Texture::setFilter(osg::Texture::FilterParameter, osg::Texture::FilterMode) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::NodeVisitor::apply(osg::Node&) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to  « vtable for osg::Array »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to  « osgEarth::GeoTransform::GeoTransform() »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to  « typeinfo for osg::Group »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::Shader::Shader(osg::Shader::Type) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::NodeVisitor::apply(osg::ProxyNode&) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::Node::getOrCreateStateSet() »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::Texture2D::Texture2D() »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::NodeVisitor::apply(osg::OcclusionQueryNode&) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::StateSet::setMode(unsigned int, unsigned int) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::BufferData::~BufferData() »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::StateSet::getAttribute(osg::StateAttribute::Type, unsigned int) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to  « typeinfo for osg::NodeVisitor »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osgText::TextBase::setDrawMode(unsigned int) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::Transform::Transform(osg::Transform const&, osg::CopyOp const&) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::Object::Object(osg::Object const&, osg::CopyOp const&) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to  « vtable for osg::DrawArrays »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::Referenced::Referenced(bool) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « vtable for osg::Box »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::StateSet::setAttribute(osg::StateAttribute*, unsigned int) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::StateSet::setAttributeAndModes(osg::StateAttribute*, unsigned int) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « typeinfo for osg::Geode »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::Group::releaseGLObjects(osg::State*) const »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to  « osg::Geode::Geode() »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::Geometry::addPrimitiveSet(osg::PrimitiveSet*) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::NodeVisitor::apply(osg::PagedLOD&) »
../inet/src/libINET.so : undefined reference to « osg::LineStipple::LineStipple() »
.
.
.

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:104: recipe for target 'out/gcc-release//SaaS' failed
make: *** [out/gcc-release//SaaS] Error 1
```

Can someone help me on this, I've been trying to solve the problem for three days without success.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest version of OMNeT++ (5.4.1, soon 5.5 will be released, too) and INET 3.6.5 or INET 4.1.1.

osgEarth changed its API and older versions of INET do not compile anymore.

The other solution is to disable osg and osgEarth support in OMNeT++ (see the configure.user file) if you do not need and 3D visualization in your project.

Comment: I am using OMNeT++ 5.4.1 and INET 4.1.1. And for the other solution, I need 3D visualization so I can't disable it.

Comment: Ups, you are right. This seems to be an issue that the OpenSceneGraph libraries are not linked in. Make sure that OMNeT++ correctly configured to use OSG. Test the samples/osg-earth example in omnet to make sure everything works in omnet.

Comment: I got these errors : 0:1(10): error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES